# Difference between for loop construct vs range keyword in go

Tags: go

Consider the following code which just prints all the ENV vars

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    for i, env := range os.Environ() {
        fmt.Println(i, env)
    }
}
```

Here, os.Environ() is supposed to return [array of strings([] string](https://golang.org/src/os/env.go?s=2990:3013#L96)), to loop over it. I need to to use range keyword & also for loop. Question is:

1. Why are both for & range required? is it possible to use for loop for this as `[]string` is already an array & we can iterate over arrays right?
2. In the above code what does `range` do? and what does `for` loop does?

Sorry if this question is too stupid, I am just starting with Go

Comment: Replace every instance of "array" with "slice" in your question. [The two are very different things in Go](https://blog.golang.org/slices).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in [Range Clauses](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Range):

> A range clause provides a way to iterate over a array, slice, string, map, or channel.

If you want to iterate over an `[]string`, you need `range`.

A [For statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) doesn't always use range.

```
ForStmt = "for" [ Condition | ForClause | RangeClause ] Block .
```

You have:

> - In its simplest form, a "`for`" statement specifies the repeated execution of a block as long as a boolean condition evaluates to true
> - A "for" statement with a `ForClause` is also controlled by its condition, but additionally it may specify an init and a post statement, such as an assignment, an increment or decrement statement
> - A "for" statement with a "range" clause iterates through all entries of an array, slice, string or map, or values received on a channel. For each entry it assigns iteration values to corresponding iteration variables if present and then executes the block.

Comment: It makes sense now, Thank you!

Comment: The quotation from https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I find the accepted answer slightly confusing as it doesn't directly directly address the questions.

So to answer your questions.

1. `for range` is one loop style you can use to access the elements in the environment slice returned from os.Environ(), but as I show below you can use the other for loop style. You will see the differences below.
2. `range` in this for loop is the construct you use that will provide a copy and the index for each of the elements in the slice.

To summarize, there are basically two forms of the for loop construct in go (actually 3, but we're only concerned with two here).

One uses the `range` keyword, and the other does not.

The `for ... range` version creates a copy of the item in the slice you are iterating over.  The other, does not and you must access it by reference.

```
func main() {
    for i, env := range os.Environ() {
        fmt.Println(i, env)
    }
}
```

Here is how you would write the for loop without using range construct:

```
func main() {
    env := os.Environ()
    for i := 0; i < len(env); i++ {
        fmt.Println(i, env[i])
    }
}
```

I also found a third option which looks tidy and has the same advantage as option 2.

```
func main() {
    env := os.Environ()
    for i := range env {
        fmt.Println(i, env[i])
    }
}
```

The first approach is nice and clean, but the second provides better performance because it doesn't do a copy.  Both have their place. I would generally use `range`, but where you need it, the traditional C-like loop is available.

Answer (score 0):

One notable difference if **for range** creates copy of each the objects from slice/array.
Have a look at following code snippet.
https://go.dev/play/p/MHaCXj-Y5WD