# Strange TypeScript Syntax

Tags: typescript, for-loop, go, syntax, range

I was looking at a TypeScript function to calculate an average run time and I encountered some strange syntax I haven't seen before:

```
    func averageRuntimeInSeconds(runs []Run) float64 {
    var totalTime int
    var failedRuns int
    for _, run := range runs {
        if run.Failed {
            failedRuns++
        } else {
            totalTime += run.Time
        }
    }

    averageRuntime := float64(totalTime) / float64(len(runs) - failedRuns) / 1000
    return averageRuntime
}
```

What does the

> :=

symbol mean on the 4th line?
Also on the 4th line of that code, the syntax for the **for loop** looks very strange to me. There are no parentheses. What is going on there? What kind of for loop is that?

And lastly, what does the **range** keyword do?

Comment: It is Golang not a TypeScript.

Comment: [What is the difference between := and = in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512919/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-go), [Range Clauses (go Wiki)](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Range), [Difference between for loop construct vs range keyword in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955792/difference-between-for-loop-construct-vs-range-keyword-in-go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RAZAFINARIVO has pointed out in the comments of my question, the function is actually from the Golang language, not Typescript. I was mistaken in thinking it was Typescript. Thanks RAZAFINARIVO!

Comment: the best way to say thank you on stackoverflow is to upvote or accept other person's answer